# PHP - Convert JSON Format into array

Tags: php, json

I am getting a response from a payment device in json format. I want to access that in array.
Here is my json response

```
    Without OrderId:- 
doInBackground: {"amount":"1.00","reason":"Transaction declined by card","transactionId":"219775","transactionData":"{\"result\":\"success\",\"transactionId\":219775,\"billNumber\":\"101:879209:675466.0\",\"applicationId\":\"A0000001523010\",\"tsi\":\"E800\",\"tvr\":\"0800048000\",\"date\":\"21-06-2017\",\"currency\":\"NA\",\"tcResult\":\"0\",\"amount\":\"1.00\",\"terminalId\":\"98207200\",\"tipAmount\":\"0.00\",\"time\":\"15:41:58\",\"batchNumber\":\"1\",\"receiptLink\":\"http:\\\/\\\/test.mosambee.in\\\/ROOT1\\\/ViewReciept.do?action=mobileReceipt&txnId=219775\",\"merchantId\":\"P587956\",\"transactionStatus\":\"Declined\",\"deviceId\":1449,\"cardHolderName\":\"RK9018388863             \\\/\",\"invoiceNumber\":\"40\",\"approvalCode\":\"689653\",\"transactionMode\":\"CHIP\",\"cardType\":\"Invalid Card\",\"message\":\"Transaction declined by card\",\"transactionType\":\"Sale\",\"retrievalReferenceNumber\":\"000000219775\",\"cashBack\":\"NA\",\"cardNumber\":\"652163XXXXXX1698\",\"isSignatureRequired\":false,\"orderId\":\"101\",\"shipperId\":\"879209\"}","result":"false","reasonCode":"NA"}
```

I tried json decode but it is not working. it gives me empty data.
    I tried:

```
$data = json_decode('Without OrderId:- 
            doInBackground: {"amount":"1.00","reason":"Transaction declined by card","transactionId":"219775","transactionData":"{\"result\":\"success\",\"transactionId\":219775,\"billNumber\":\"101:879209:675466.0\",\"applicationId\":\"A0000001523010\",\"tsi\":\"E800\",\"tvr\":\"0800048000\",\"date\":\"21-06-2017\",\"currency\":\"NA\",\"tcResult\":\"0\",\"amount\":\"1.00\",\"terminalId\":\"98207200\",\"tipAmount\":\"0.00\",\"time\":\"15:41:58\",\"batchNumber\":\"1\",\"receiptLink\":\"http:\\\/\\\/test.mosambee.in\\\/ROOT1\\\/ViewReciept.do?action=mobileReceipt&txnId=219775\",\"merchantId\":\"P587956\",\"transactionStatus\":\"Declined\",\"deviceId\":1449,\"cardHolderName\":\"RK9018388863             \\\/\",\"invoiceNumber\":\"40\",\"approvalCode\":\"689653\",\"transactionMode\":\"CHIP\",\"cardType\":\"Invalid Card\",\"message\":\"Transaction declined by card\",\"transactionType\":\"Sale\",\"retrievalReferenceNumber\":\"000000219775\",\"cashBack\":\"NA\",\"cardNumber\":\"652163XXXXXX1698\",\"isSignatureRequired\":false,\"orderId\":\"101\",\"shipperId\":\"879209\"}","result":"false","reasonCode":"NA"}', true);
        return $data;
```

This gives me empty data.

Comment: Yeah, that's not *just* JSON…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ian noted, your data is invalid. But if you strip off `Without OrderId:- doInBackground:` it will work.

```
$data = json_decode('{"amount":"1.00","reason":"Transaction declined by card","transactionId":"219775","transactionData":"{\"result\":\"success\",\"transactionId\":219775,\"billNumber\":\"101:879209:675466.0\",\"applicationId\":\"A0000001523010\",\"tsi\":\"E800\",\"tvr\":\"0800048000\",\"date\":\"21-06-2017\",\"currency\":\"NA\",\"tcResult\":\"0\",\"amount\":\"1.00\",\"terminalId\":\"98207200\",\"tipAmount\":\"0.00\",\"time\":\"15:41:58\",\"batchNumber\":\"1\",\"receiptLink\":\"http:\\\/\\\/test.mosambee.in\\\/ROOT1\\\/ViewReciept.do?action=mobileReceipt&txnId=219775\",\"merchantId\":\"P587956\",\"transactionStatus\":\"Declined\",\"deviceId\":1449,\"cardHolderName\":\"RK9018388863             \\\/\",\"invoiceNumber\":\"40\",\"approvalCode\":\"689653\",\"transactionMode\":\"CHIP\",\"cardType\":\"Invalid Card\",\"message\":\"Transaction declined by card\",\"transactionType\":\"Sale\",\"retrievalReferenceNumber\":\"000000219775\",\"cashBack\":\"NA\",\"cardNumber\":\"652163XXXXXX1698\",\"isSignatureRequired\":false,\"orderId\":\"101\",\"shipperId\":\"879209\"}","result":"false","reasonCode":"NA"}');
print_r($data);
```

Comment: i am getting '\' in my data. How to remove that..?

Comment: @JayMomaya Just print here what type of data you get with '\' in your question please?

Comment: He mentioned the response is from an API, so left out the explanation as to why

Comment: @JayMomaya You can remove it using `$result =  str_replace('\','',$data);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a valid response, what do you expect?

`Without OrderId:- 
        doInBackground:`

isn't valid.  After you run `json_decode` on this string, if you run `json_last_error_msg`, you get "Syntax error."

You must strip away the parts of this message that are not key-value pairs before passing it to `json_decode`.

You may also verify this by testing your string on https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: Actually, JSON is just plain text. The text representation of some Javascript data structure. It can be an object or an array or a scalar value as well.

Comment: @axiac JSON is an acronym... JavaScript Object Notation, JSON is a structured document comprised of objects

Comment: Objects exist only in memory. JSON is text. It can be stored in a file or sent through the network. And there is no such thing like "JSON object". I'm not the one who downvoted your answer, though.

Comment: @axiac If you're going to strip things down like that, programming is only text, objects are just 1's and 0's. How is storage and memory come into this?

Comment: I actually agree with the spirit of Ian's answer and added some more details.   The objections that are being raised seem a bit pedantic to me.  If you want json_decode to work, pass in a frickin' object that can be parsed.  It can't parse spaghetti.

Answer (score -1):

do : -> echo json_decode('json/array name');